# Заполнить 5-ти мерный массив одним циклом

Tags: java, массивы

Всем привет. Нужно заполнить 5-ти мерный массив 1 циклом....
Подскажите пожалуйста, а то в голову ничего не приходит.

```
int[][][][][] array = new int[2][2][2][2][2];
```

Comment: Рекурсией пройдитесь. Тоже нельзя?

Comment: ТЗ именно циклом организовать и именно только одним....

Comment: написать свой паттерн итератор и заполнить через него

Comment: [`Stream.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) считается за цикл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заполнить можно таким образом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
            array[(i >> 4) & 1][(i >> 3) & 1][(i >> 2) & 1][(i >> 1) & 1][i & 1] = i;
}
```

По сути мы берём цифры числа `0 <= i <= 31` в двоичном представлении и подставляем  их в соответствующие индексы массива. Например, при i = 20 = 10100₂ будет заполнен элемент `array[1][0][1][0][0]`. Таким образом, мы проходим по всем элементам. Это можно проверить, выведя все элементы:

```
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < 2; i1++)
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 2; i2++)
        for(int i3 = 0; i3 < 2; i3++)
            for(int i4 = 0; i4 < 2; i4++)
                for(int i5 = 0; i5 < 2; i5++)
                    System.out.print(array[i1][i2][i3][i4][i5] + " ");
```

Вывод:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```